# Синонимизировать [печать] и [printing]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать [печать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c) и [printing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printing) в пользу [печать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c).